# JOOQ throws cannot access java.util.concurrent.Flow for version 3.17.2

Tags: java, jooq

I'm trying to run a simple example with JOOQ, but It hasn't been possible. I'm using IntelliJ as IDE and making sure that I'm using the correct JDK.

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71561604/jooq-throws-class-file-for-java-util-concurrent-flow-not-found-for-where-conditi) does not apply since I'm using the JDK 18 and the JOOQ version of 3.17.2.

This is the code snippet:

```java
    public static void connectToDb() {
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javaspark-db";

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password)) {
            DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
            Author AUTHOR = Author.AUTHOR;
            // Getting error just here at select()
            Result<Record> result = dslContext.select().from(AUTHOR).fetch();

            for (Record r : result) {
                Integer id = r.getValue(AUTHOR.ID);
                String firstName = r.getValue(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME);
                String lastName = r.getValue(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME);

                System.out.println("ID: " + id + " first name: " + firstName + " last name: " + lastName);
            }

        }

        // For the sake of this tutorial, let's keep exception handling simple
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

```
/Users/xxxx/xxxx/todo-spark-app/src/main/java/app/Application.java:26:56
java: cannot access java.util.concurrent.Flow
  class file for java.util.concurrent.Flow not found
```

The maven dependencies:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>3.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>3.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>3.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What's the commplete error stack trace?

Comment: The error only shows what you see on the question, it seems it never gets to the catch block.

Comment: It's failing building the project.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `JDK18` and not `JDK8`?

Comment: Well, it was a silly mistake after all. My IDE and env vars were all configured to use JAVA18, but my pom.xml file still had 8 as compiler target. I will include an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well after all it seems that I forgot to change the `maven.compiler.source` and target in my pom.xml file.

So in my pom.xml file I changed this:

```
     <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

To be like this:

```
     <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

And that got my app running. Silly mistake indeed.